# Is my understanding and conceptualization of async vs sync correct?

Tags: node.js, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization, backend

Ive just started learning node.js and back-end programing concepts. I have a rough of idea of the difference between async and sync and was wondering if my following logic is correct in the understanding of the concepts.

Async type connection ---

A user request to make a new post. ( Clicks make new post button )

Server sends back a webpage with the required input fields necessary for a post eg ( title, body, tags ) such as this stackoverflow post im creating.
Once data is received client sends a packet back saying it received the data and the Thread is ended.

User fills in the input fields and clicks submit and new thread
opens

Server takes in the data from the input fields and thread ends.

Server updates database. Task finished.

Sync Connection ---

Client ask server to make a new post. Thread opens until
client fills out input fields.
 Server continues to use processing power to keep the thread open until user clicks submit. User clicks submit and server updates database thread ended. Task ended.

So basically a async connection is just small sync connection ?
Where a sync connection ends task and thread at the same time.
While a async connection splits the tasks into multiple threads. Until task finishes.

I hope this is somewhat correct.

Comment: No, your understanding is not correct. Node is single-threaded. It's a single process that serves the requests (unless a cluster is used). Threads aren't opened and closed. It's unclear what you mean by 'async vs sync connections'. Where did you get these connection concepts from? What you're describing seems to be very far from anything that could happen in real life, so it's unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: Im trying to understand the difference between async and sync by breaking it down into what is happening between client and the server. I've heard metaphors comparing async connections to a restaurant with a waiter who is able to to place orders and serve orders to multiple customers. I tried to connect these metaphor to a real world application to understand deeper how the internet works . I guess my confusion is more of what a thread is and how its used by the internet. By opening and closing I was trying to suggest the thread finishing its process with that client.

Comment: I'd suggest to come up with an implementation of web server and show some code, then you will be able to ask more substantial question. How do you expect 'sync' to look like? The thing you described as 'Sync Connection' won't work as you described in Node, a server won't 'wait' for client, there will be separate requests. I don't understand what kind of 'sync connection' you refer to.